# How do I serialize ActiveModel errors for later translation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, internationalization, jobs

I have a situation wherein a user submits some data to a web server (Rails) that will be processed in the background:

```
POST /fibonacci/6012 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

The server responds with a link to the background job that the user can use to check the status:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Location: http://example.com/jobs/5699121
```

The important thing to note is that *any* (authorized) user can check the status of the job. This means that I have to communicate any error messages from the worker back to the web server *symbolically*. I can't figure out a way to do so for ActiveModel errors. For example:

```
class FibonacciCalculation
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_reader :input
  validates_presence_of :input
  validates_inclusion_of :input, :in => 0..10_000,
                                 :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(params = {})
    @input = params[:input]
  end

  def output
    # do fibonacci calculation
  end
end
```

If I create such an object with `FibonacciCalculation.new(:input => -5)` and then get out the errors, I get an `ActiveModel::Errors` object, but I can't figure out how to serialize that. Asking for `errors[:input]` gives me `["can't be blank"]` or `["is not included in the list"]`, which are already translated. Similarly, `errors.as_json` returns something like

```
`{ "errors" => [ "can't be blank" ] }`
```

How can I get something like `{ :input => [:blank] }` or `{ :input => [:inclusion] }`?

Answer (score 3):

`ActiveModel::Errors` does the translation as soon as the error is added, and it doesn't store the key symbolically. That leaves two ways to get the data back out:

#### 1. Monkey-patching

```
ActiveModel::Errors.class_eval do
  old_generate_message = instance_method(:generate_message)
  def generate_message(attribute, type = :invalid, options = {})
    options[:type] ||
      old_generate_message.bind(self).call(attribute, type, options)
  end
end
```

#### 2. Overriding the translations

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        blank: blank
        inclusion: inclusion
        ...
```

Both cases are tricky for me because the same codebase runs both the workers and the web servers. Thus, I have to conditionally load either the monkey-patch or the translation overrides.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, I created a small gem to handle this case, Hopefully this will help someone : https://github.com/Intrepidd/activemodel_errors_type

You can call `model.errors.with_types` to get the types of your errors prior to the translation.